# Leverage 301 HTTP code for email address migration

Tags: email, smtp, 301-redirect

Is it possible to leverage `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` for email address migrations to ask the sender to sender the further messages to another email address?

### UPDATE

I'm aware of differences between HTTP and SMTP and other email related protocols (IMAP, POP3). What I'm looking for is a similar concept like HTTP 301 to be applied to emails.

For example, when you want to move your website to another domain you leverage HTTP 301 to let search engines know that you moved to another address. Ultimately, when your old domain is down, users can easily find the new one. I want to know if there are any similar solutions for moving the emails. The search engine plays a key role here for websites but is there any sort of similar party or any other solution that can help users find the new email address especially when the old email address no longer exists?

Comment: `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` is HTTP Protocol ... E-Mail is SMTP Protocol ... both things do not have any thing in common!!! If you want redirect E-Mails this is not possible with HTTP 301

Comment: Yeah, I understand the difference. I'm looking for a similar concept for emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no search engines for moving email addresses.  Most administrators would not want their valid email listed.  However, there are lists circulating among spammers, although they are not well maintained.

If you are moving to a new domain, retain the old domain.  Use the same MX for for both domains and configure the mail server to accept both domains.  Both of the domains should have working (someone handles the email) for abuse, hostmaster, webmaster and postmaster.  Some common business related aliases include support, info and jobs.  (Warning: Spam is often sent to the business aliases even if they have never been published.)

Update the mail links on the website to the new domain.  You can use some of the following techniques to prompt users to update their address books.  You can have the people handling the email include an update when responding to email to an address with the old domain.

The correct message code for invalid users is 550.  Depending on your server software you may be able to provide new address with an aliases such as:

```
Old.user:  :fail: New address is old.user@example.com
```

You might be able to forward and send a fail message to the sender using an alias pair.  Test before using.  Try something like:

```
Old.user:  xx-old.user, new.user@example.com
xx-old.user :fail: New address is use.user@example.com
```

In Exim4, you could use a separate alias file for redirects with an additional alias transport.  This would allow you to add a fake bounce message in the ACL processing recipient addresses.  Other software may have similar capabilities.

If you are going to forward the message you may need to do sender address rewriting.  This will reduce the likelyhood that the forwarded message is bounced at the new server.  (If you control the new receiving server, configure your old server as a trusted relay.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe this is the best possible answer but I've updated the question to give more ideas what I'm looking for. Please update your answer based on this update if you think it's necessary before I accept this one as the correct answer.